# Selenium grab response from server after clicking a button

Tags: selenium

When I click a button using selenium, it fires ajax request and gets json response.

I'd like to grab that json response.

Answer (score 0):

You probably looking for something similar to [BrowserMob Proxy](https://bmp.lightbody.net/)

**EDIT**: Selenium does **NOT** provide such solution, since it's purpose is to mimic user-side testing (Navigate, click, set text).

Comment: The question ask for selenium solution... can you edit/close?

Comment: "BrowserMob proxy is based on technology developed in the Selenium open source project and a commercial load testing and monitoring service originally called BrowserMob and now part of Neustar". And it is exactly what is needed for the job.

Comment: I think with the new version of Selenium 4, you can use DevTools for this purpose.